How to partition a weighted graph into subgraphs?
I'm wondering if there might be a well known solution to this problem.  I have a graph that I want to partition into several smaller graphs.  Each edge has a cost that indicates how expensive it is to move from one vertex to another.  I want to break this graph into smaller neighborhoods where the cost of moving within a neighborhood is minimized.
If an edge directly connecting two nodes {V0, Vn} is high, it is possible there is some other chain of edges {V0, V1, V2, ..., Vn - 1, Vn} that has a lower total cost.  So the cost of going from V0 to Vn could be seen as the minimum cost of any connecting chain of edges.
I don't know in advance how many neighborhoods I am going to end up with.  However I'd like to avoid having a lot of tiny neighborhoods.  Ideally I'd have some sort of tunable parameter which affects how many pieces this larger graph is broken up into.
Is there a good way to go about doing this?

create a new graph where each edge between node $i$ and $j$ is weighted with the minimum total cost to move from $i$ to $j$. Then set a parameter $\lambda$ and remove all the edges iin this new graph that weight more than $\lambda$. The connected components of what's left are your community. The bigger $\lambda$ is, the bigger the communities will be

@Exodd I can't understand your solution completely. Lets say I have graph $G = (V, E)$ where $V = {1, 2, 3}$ and $E = {(1, 2, 20), (2, 3, 30)}$. Then the new graph you talk about will have edge matrix as $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 20 & 50 \ 20 & 0 & 30 \ 50 & 30 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Now if you put $\lambda=40$, which edges are you going to remove?

@kitfox How do you define "cost of moving within a neighborhood"? Is it the maximum distance between two nodes in that neighborhood, or the sum of distances over all possible pair of vertices in that neighborhood? Also when you say "cost of moving within a neighborhood is minimized", do you want the sum over all neighborhoods minimized, or the maximum over all neighborhoods minimized?

The maximum distance between two nodes is minimized.  The problem I'm trying to apply this to is breaking a 3D mesh into pieces.  I was thinking that a good way to do this is to create 'flat' patches where flatness can be defined by the summed normal of all faces within the patch.  So if adjacent faces F1 and F2 have normals N1 and N2, you can define a relative flatness score of s(N1, N2) = 1 - dot(N1, N2).

If you take a walk across the surface, as you move from face to face your walk will be the sum of the flatness score of every pair of faces you traverse.  So the flatness between any two faces is the value of the minimum walk between the two faces.  I'm hoping to use this heuristic to break my mesh into a small number of flat-ish pieces.

I would recommend looking into spectral clustering.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering

Ng, Andrew, Michael Jordan, and Yair Weiss. "On spectral clustering:
Analysis and an algorithm." Advances in neural information processing
systems 14 (2001).
https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-spectral.pdf

Roughly, you compute the smoothest few eigen modes of a (weighted) graph laplacian. Then in this spectral basis you can perform simple clustering like k-means, or linear clustering.
Intuitively, imagine connecting nodes in your graph with physical springs, where the spring stiffness is a function of the weight of the edge. Now hit your spring network with a hammer and watch it vibrate. Parts of the network that are more tightly connected will tend to coherently vibrate together more, which makes those parts of the network group together in the spectral basis.
